# three.js: rotate tetrahedron on correct axis

Tags: javascript, 3d, rotation, three.js

I have to display a rotating tetrahedron in an animated HTML5 graphic, using three.js.

When i create the object, it's upside down, but it should be on the ground with one surface, like on this screenshot: http://www10.pic-upload.de/08.10.12/v3nnz25zo65q.png

This is the code for rotating the object, at the moment. Stored in render() function. But the axis is incorrect and the object is rotating wrong.

```
object.useQuaternion = true;
var rotateQuaternion_ = new THREE.Quaternion();
rotateQuaternion_.setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 1), 0.2 * (Math.PI / 180));
object.quaternion.multiplySelf(rotateQuaternion_);
object.quaternion.normalize();
```

(copied from [Three.JS - how to set rotation axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816623/three-js-how-to-set-rotation-axis/11829484#11829484))

This is the result at the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/DkhT3/

How can i access the correct axis to move/rotate the tetrahedron on the ground?

Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't do what you copied. It is not correct.

I am assuming that what you want to do is to start off with a tetrahedron that is right-side-up to begin with. One thing you can do is to modify `THREE.TetrahedronGeometry()` to use four vertices that produce the tetrahedron that you want.

If you want to use the existing code, then what you have to do is to apply a rotation to the geometry right after it is created, like so:

```js
const geometry = new THREE.TetrahedronGeometry( 10, 0 );
geometry.applyMatrix4( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis( new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, - 1 ).normalize(), Math.atan( Math.sqrt( 2 ) ) ) );
geometry.translate( 0, 10 / 3, 0 ); // optional, so it sits on the x-z plane
```

(Determining the proper rotation angle requires a bit of math, but it turns out to be the arctangent of the sqrt( 2 ) in this case, in radians.)

three.js r.146

Comment: this doesn't seem to work properly in threejs r143. i get a result like this: https://i.ibb.co/0nDYcsX/image.png

Comment: @alexia It works correctly for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Download three.js from [http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/Three.js] library and put in the below HTML code. 
You will get good output.

<!Doctype html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
    <title>I like shapes</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <style>
     canvas{
     width: 100%; 
     height: 100% 
     }
    body{
    background: url(mathematics.jpg);
    width: 800px; 
    height: 500px;
    }
     </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="three.js"></script>

    <script> 
    // creating a Scene
    var scene = new THREE.Scene(); 

    // Adding Perspective Camera
    // NOTE: There are 3 cameras: Orthographic, Perspective and Combined.   
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000); 


    //create WebGL renderer 
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    //Drawing a Tetrahedron.
    var pyramidgeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 0.8, 4, 4, false);

    //Change colour of Pyramid using Wireframe
    var pyramidmaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe: true, color: 0x0ff000});
    var pyramid = new THREE.Mesh(pyramidgeometry, pyramidmaterial); //This creates the cone
    pyramid.position.set(3.1,0,0);
    scene.add(pyramid);

    //moving camera outward of centre to Z-axis, because Cube is being created at the centre
    camera.position.z = 5;

    //we have a scene, a camera, a cube and a renderer. 

    /*A render loop essentially makes the renderer draw the scene 60 times per second.
    I have used requestAnimationFrame() function.*/
    var render = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    /*cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.z += 0.01;*/

    pyramid.rotation.y += 0.01;
    pyramid.rotation.x += 0.01;
    pyramid.rotation.z += 0.01;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
    // calling the function
    render();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```