# react-three-fiber: Rotate tetrahedron "face down"

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to rotate tetrahedrons so that they lie with one side facing downwards, like how they would be if they where physical objects that you placed on a floor.

[I expected this SO answer to solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784455/three-js-rotate-tetrahedron-on-correct-axis)

After applying the accepted answer by giving the tetrahedron the applyMatrix property, my code looked like this:

```
const Triangle = ({ position, color }) => {
  const mesh = useRef(null);
  return (
    <mesh castShadow ref={mesh} position={position}>
      <tetrahedronGeometry
        attach="geometry"
        args={[0.6, 0]}
        applyMatrix={new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(
          new THREE.Vector3(2, 0, -1).normalize(),
          Math.atan(Math.sqrt(2))
        )}
      />
      <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color={color} />
    </mesh>
  );
};
```

However, the rotation of my tetrahedrons did not change. What am I doing wrong?

This is my current code: [fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-field-ggqel?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

applyMatrix is a function. you are overwriting it with a matrix. essentially you're doing this:

```
const geom = new THREE.TetrahedronGeometry()
geom.applyMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4()
```

put a ref on the mesh or the geometry, then use useLayoutEffect to call the function.